# Google Apps Script to initate browser download when clicking on a Google Drive file

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some particular files stored on my Google Drive with the extension of "bch".  I need to be able to have a user click on this file in Google Drive and have it initiate the browser download prompt.

I was thinking that the way to do this would be to create a script that has the file information passed to it as a parameter and then execute the download request.  I was hoping to define the file extension in the script so all files with this extension would be defaulted to run this script/app in Google Drive.

Has anyone done anything like this?  If you could point me to some Google Apps Script examples I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior on Google Drive? Also, I don't believe it's possible to automatically trigger a download using Google Apps Script. The user always have to click on a link themselves to trigger a download.

Comment: If I left-click on a file with the extension of .bch in Google Drive, the Google preview comes up and since this is a file that uses a local viewer installed on a PC to view, the Google preview can't preview it and generates an error saying "Sorry, an error has occurred". The idea would be to replace the default action of a .bch file to a Google Drive App that would instead initiate a browser download so the file can be viewed on the local PC.